# What does ** mean in C++?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
bool insertInFront( IntElement **head, int data ){
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    if ( !newElem ) return false;

    newElen->data = data;
    *head = newElem; // Correctly updates head
    return true;
}
```

I am new to C++, coming from Java. I get the `*` for indirection syntax, but `**` is not listed on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators

I found this example on page 28 of [*Programming Interviews Exposed*](http://maniali.wikispaces.com/file/view/Programming+Interviews+Exposed.PDF)

**Update**

I realize that this question is naive, and I probably could have found an answer through other means. Obviously, I am new to the language. Still, asking "What does `**` mean?" is not well supported online for someone who does not know that `**` is a pointer operation. There are very few relevant results when searching `C ** syntax` or `C++ ** meaning`. Additionally, using `ctrl + f` to search `**` in the wiki page above, and other documentation, doesn't return any matches at all.

I just wanted to clarify, from a beginner's perspective, that this question is hard to distinguish from the duplicates. Of course, the answer is the same :-) Thank you for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: Yes, it is listed on that page, as the case when `a` is `*A` for some `A`.

Comment: @rubenvb I see what you did there. :D

Comment: @John what did I do? I'm not following.

Comment: @rubenvb Oh I thought you did it on purpose. The link you posted points to a link, that points to the post.

Comment: @John oh wow. And here I was just thinking I marked a question as a duplicate `:-P`. Nice going me :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific `**` operator in C++, instead it's two separate asterisks, and asterisks in a declaration denotes pointer declaration.

So in the declaration

```
IntElement **head
```

the argument `head` is declared to be a pointer to a pointer to `IntElement`.

Comment: Congrats for the new avatar.

Comment: Well.. I need a congratulations too, just got a new job ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Then congrats to you too! :)

Answer (score 2):

Its meaning:

```
int a;                // integer
int *ptrA = &a        // pointer to a integer
int **PtrPtrA = &ptrA // point to pointer to a integer
```

How can it be used:

```
void function_nochange(int *pA  ) {   pA   = &b;  } 
void function_change  (int **ppA) {   *ppA = &b;  } 

int a;
int b;
void test()
{
  int *ptrA = &a

  function_nochange(ptrA)
  // here ptrA still point to int a since ptrA was copied

  function_change(&ptrA)
  // here ptrA point to int b since ptrA was passed as pointer 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**VariableName means pointer to pointer(a chain of pointers) in C++

You can find good tutorials here :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_pointer.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer

Comment: Thanks, these tutorials are very helpful. Especially for C++ beginners.