# What does char*** mean in C?

Tags: c

I need help understanding what char*** means and how do I initialize a variable that is of type char***.

For example, if there is a function that reads the lines of a file, while keeping track of the number of lines and printing out each line with its corresponding number:

```
void read_lines(FILE* fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines){}
```

What would char*** represent in this case and how would I initialize the variable lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768382/920069

Comment: [Read a book first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714) instead of just asking here on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537889/what-does-mean-in-c)

Comment: Beware: being accused of being a [Three-star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment.

Comment: It usually means you need to rearrange or refactor your code to provide a return of some type that can be assigned, etc.. so has to no longer be a Three-star Programmer. (that said, there are some instances with pointer where it may be a reasonable choice, such as where the address of a *poiner-to-pointer-to-type* is required) In your case you could change your declaration to `char **read_lines(FILE* fp, char** lines, int* num_lines){}` and return a pointer to the modified `lines` for assignment back in the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-`char`.  In this case, it's very likely to be an *output* parameter.  Since C passes arguments by value, output parameters require an extra level of [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection).  That is, the `read_lines` function wants to give the caller a `char**`, and to accomplish that via an output parameter, it needs to take a *pointer* to a `char**`.  Likely all you'd need to do to invoke it is:

```c
char** lines = null;
int num_lines;
read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
```

Also see [C Programming: malloc() inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function/2838207#2838207).

Answer (score 2):

> I need help understanding what char*** means ...

The `char***` type is a pointer.  A pointer to a `char **`.  [p as pointer to pointer to pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char***+p%3B)

```
char*** p;
```

> ... and how do I initialize a variable that is of type char***.

```
char*** p1 = NULL;  // Initialize p with the null pointer constant.

char *q[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
char*** p2 = &q;  // Initialize p2 with the address of q

char ***p3 = malloc(sizeof *p3);  // Allocate memory to p3.  Enough for 1 `char **`.
....
free(p3); // free memory when done.
```

Comment: `char p3 = malloc(sizeof *p3);`...?